# How to add google api to grunt build

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, gruntjs, bower, webstorm

I'm fairly new to Grunt, Bower and Yoeman so please forgive me if I'm not asking the right question.  I've added the angular-google-maps module to my build and set it up manually and everything looks fine.  However whenever I restart my project in Webstorm or build using grunt, my google maps api reference keeps getting lost.  I've added the google and lodash dependencies to the package.json file and those references are being added just fine.  However, how do I add a dependency to an api or should I just be putting the reference before the bower/components block? I've been searching the web for the last day or so and nothing seems to address this that I've found.

Here's an example of the api I need to add -

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to put your reference outside of the `<!-- bower:js --><!-- endbower -->` block in your HTML. This section is overwritten by [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) when you build your application